How to Reuse Android URI from the Result of ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE?
I have the desire to request permissions to the Documents directory via an ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE intent action and then reuse the uri later in the app flow or one subsequent app sessions, but I am not sure how.
This is what I have tried.  In onActivityResult():
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == directoryPickerID) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                data?.data?.also { uri ->
                    if (uri.toString() == "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ADocuments") {
                        val documentsTree = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, uri) ?: return
                        val childDocuments = documentsTree.listFiles()
                        for (childDocument in childDocuments) {
                            childDocument.name?.let { it1 -> Log.d("documentsUri", it1) }
                        }
                        with(defaultSharedPreferences.edit()) {
                            putString("documentsUri", uri.toString())
                            apply()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

Then later in the app flow in the same session or a later one:
        if (defaultSharedPreferences.contains("documentsUri")) {
            val documentsUri = Uri.parse(defaultSharedPreferences.getString("documentsUri", ""))
            val documentsTree = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, documentsUri) ?: return
            val childDocuments = documentsTree.listFiles()
            for (childDocument in childDocuments) {
                childDocument.name?.let { it1 -> Log.d("documentsUri2", it1) }
            }
        }

The problem is, that when I do this, the restored Uri does not work the same as the previous one.  No files/directories are seen etc.
How do I get a Uri with permissions again without having to ask the user to interact again?

I think takePersistableUriPermission should do what you want. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#takePersistableUriPermission(android.net.Uri,%20int) call it on your onActivityResult

You are correct.  Adding that to onActivityResult() does the trick.  I had assumed (incorrectly) that was only needed for ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT because I only saw examples of it being used for that intent action and when you do a ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE it specifically tells the user that the app when have permanent access to the directory.

Note that your code assumes content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ADocuments is "the Documents directory". There is no guarantee that you will get that Uri for that directory selection. Moreover, if you are using the Storage Access Framework, it really should not matter what document tree that the user wishes to use, so long as it has the documents that the user wants your app to interact with.
